# Split columns by delimitator and place in new columns in the same data frame R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to split columns in a dataframe and place them next to each other based on a single factor column. I would like to turn this:

```
   TOD  Value
1  Day   135
2  Day   513
3  Day   567
4  Day   848
5  Day   578
6  Night 145
7  Night 267
8  Night 589
9  Night 258
10 Night 278
```

and turn it into this:

```
   TOD  Value TOD_2 Value_2
1  Day   135  Night  145
2  Day   513  Night  267
3  Day   567  Night  589
4  Day   848  Night  258
5  Day   578  Night  278
```

How do I do this?

Comment: New word: 'delimitator`. Sounds like a name for a genetically modified potato.

Comment: @IRTFM Let's make a new file format .psv which stands for potato separated values.

Comment: tbh, I saw the word 'deliminator' on another post and decided to use it without really understanding what it means, or if its a word. I study fish, not grammar.

Comment: It's not really grammar, but rather vocabulary. If you want grammur, then ok ..."Delimit" is the verb; "delimiter" is the noun.

Answer (score 2):

A tidy solution using `group_split` and `bind_cols`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "   TOD  Value
1  Day   135
2  Day   513
3  Day   567
4  Day   848
5  Day   578
6  Night 145
7  Night 267
8  Night 589
9  Night 258")

df <- df %>%
  group_split(TOD)

min_nrow <- min(sapply(df, nrow))

df %>%
  map(~filter(., row_number() <= min_nrow)) %>%
  Map(function(x, y) {names(x) <- paste(names(x), y, sep = "_"); x}, ., 1:length(.)) %>%
  bind_cols()
```

Comment: This also should work, and I like that it pipes things together, but is there a way to edit this so it takes into account differing numbers of rows? Say 'night has 6 rows whereas 'day' only has 5?

Comment: Sure, see my edits.

Comment: I can't have NA's, the corresponding row needs to be removed. Also this just opens up the debug console for some reason....

Comment: I cant reproduce your error, in a fresh R session with tidyverse loaded this code runs in one go for me.

Comment: its alright, i figured it out.

Comment: Also, I made some more edits. That drops any rows above the minimum. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is called `df`, you could do:

```r
do.call(cbind, split(df, df$TOD)) |> 
 setNames(c(names(df), paste0(names(df), "_2")))

#>   TOD Value TOD_2 Value_2
#> 1 Day   135 Night     145
#> 2 Day   513 Night     267
#> 3 Day   567 Night     589
#> 4 Day   848 Night     258
#> 5 Day   578 Night     278
```

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(TOD = c("Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Night", 
"Night", "Night", "Night", "Night"), Value = c(135L, 513L, 567L, 
848L, 578L, 145L, 267L, 589L, 258L, 278L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: This works well, only issue is that, in the real data frame, there are more 'night' rows than 'day' rows. Any way to account for this?

Comment: Not really. Typically when we store data, the rows represent individual observations and the columns are unique variables. The data starts in a nice, tidy format and you are trying to transform it into a shape without a clear logical structure. If the number of rows aren't equal, this makes even less sense. You would need to append a row of NA values to the bottom of the shorter group.

Comment: Would there be a way to remove the rows from the longer columns?

Comment: Yes, but it's a bit more involved, and you would lose data. Can I ask why you need to do this at all?

Comment: It's a bit complicated, the 'values' ultimately need to be adjusted by a ratio if they are night-day or day-night. It accounts for animal abundance differences from 2 points in the Mekong river (upstream and downstream). Removing extra data is fine as the true data sets are huge (acoustic data). I just need to remove the extra rows.